# Layer probability always 1

Tags: caffe, mnist, softmax

I'm using caffe/example/mnist network to classify numbers. When I give the network a picture of number it seems working ok. But when I give the network a picture not a number, the mnist trained network softmax layer gives the probabilities, which always has one probability 1 and others 0, like:

[0,0,0,...,1,0,0,0].

I think it should be something like:

[0,0.1,0.2,...,0.4,0.1,0.2],

in which case I can say that this should not be a number. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what to expect since it hasn't been trained on non-numbers and it has to give a result that sums to 1. By using Softmax, you are telling the network that there is a number, while showing it a non-number. You cannot look at its output to then determine whether it is a number or not.

Furthermore, the training data for MNIST is very stereotypical and not good for generalization. The foreground numbers are *always* 255 and the background is *always* 0. The average value will be much closer to 0, since there are more background pixels. Simply presenting an image with a mean pixel value of 100 could bias the prediction to numbers that typically have more pixels (like 8, perhaps). You can only expect to the network to generalize to similar types of stimulus. For your task, you should do quite a lot of data augmentation.

You want to allow the probability to be zeros for all numbers, which you can do by using the cross-entropy loss. This would also allow the probability to also sum to more than 1 (maximum 10). You could also try adding another class for "non-number" with the Softmax, however, then you should present non-number stimuli and number stimuli that is more similar to natural stimuli (so that it is not trivially separable).